# Filtering content based on year

Tags: javascript

I have three buttons in my layout, which lets the user filter the content accordingly to the year selected. The buttons look as the following

```
 2019      2018      2017 or berfore
```

The main data is array of an objects which looks like

```
const data = [
   {
     .....
     year: "2018"
   },
   {
     .....
     year: "2017"
   },
   {
     .....
     year: "2016"
   },
   {
     .....
     year: "2019"
   },
   {
     .....
     year: "2015"
   },

]
```

I am able to filter the content for buttons **2019** and **2018**. But when the user picks **2017 or before** it needs to filter content for the year 2017 and any previous year.

My code at the moment

```
data.filter(val => val.year === pickedYear) //filter data by year
.map(...) // do more based on filtered data
```

Any suggestions on how to handle the use case for **2017 or before**?

Comment: Are these static buttons?  What determines that the years and the logic?

Comment: No the buttons are not static, I am using Date() to determine the years. But I was thinking of using the difference between the picked year and current year to filter the data accordingly

Comment: I added a new answer below for consideration, selected answer is fine, but didn't find it robust — the one change I would make is to remove the `eval`, which is easily doable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can take advantage of type coercion:

```js
const data = [
   {
     year: "2018"
   },
   {
     year: "2017"
   },
   {
     year: "2016"
   },
   {
     year: "2019"
   },
   {
     year: "2015"
   }
];

const filterByYear = yearFilter => data.filter(({year}) => yearFilter > 2017 ? year == yearFilter : year < 2018);

console.log(filterByYear('2019'));
console.log(filterByYear('2018'));
console.log(filterByYear('2017 or before'))
```

Comment: I'm not a big fan of this solution since the code will always have to be maintained/updated in the future.  It works, but IMHO is not robust enough

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```js
const pickedYear = "2017";
const data = [
    {
      year: "2018"
    },
    {
      year: "2017"
    },
    {
      year: "2016"
    },
    {
      year: "2019"
    },
    {
      year: "2015"
    }
];

const filteredData = data.filter((data) => {
    return parseInt(pickedYear) > 2017 ? data.year === pickedYear : parseInt(data.year) <= 2017;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(filteredData));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of something that's a little more robust, based on the current year.  Of note it includes newer/lesser-used mechanics of the language, including:

- [function generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*)
- [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)
- a valid example of `eval` — although *really* unnecessary

It also doesn't use jQuery, though browser-compliance will vary. This isn't a complete solution, but is intended to help demonstrate the potential of where things could go:

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn.filter')
const buttonDetails = buttonGen(buttons.length) // use generator for dynamic button

// Create Buttons (text, event, value, etc)
buttons.forEach(el => {
  let data = buttonDetails.next().value
  el.value = data.value
  el.textContent = data.text
  // set button text based on 'value'
  el.addEventListener('click', filterData) // add click handler
})


// Button Click function
function filterData() {
  let button = this;
  let btn_year, op;

  if (isNaN(button.textContent)) {
    btn_year = button.value
    op = '<='
  } else {
    btn_year = button.value
    op = '=='
  }

  let data = fetchData()

  filtered_data = data.filter(data => eval(`${data.year} ${op} ${btn_year}`))
  console.log(JSON.stringify(filtered_data));
  return filtered_data
}


// Some function will most likely be an AJAX-fetch
function fetchData() {
  return [{
      year: "2018"
    },
    {
      year: "2017"
    },
    {
      year: "2016"
    },
    {
      year: "2019"
    },
    {
      year: "2015"
    }
  ]
}


// Button Info Generator
function* buttonGen(button_count) {
  const current_year = (new Date).getFullYear();
  let year = current_year
  while (true) {
    if (year <= current_year - button_count + 1)
      yield {
        text: 'earlier',
        value: year
      }
    else
      yield {
        text: year,
        value: year
      }

    year--
  }
}
```

```css
button {
  text-transform: capitalize
}
```

```html
<button class="btn filter"></button>
<button class="btn filter"></button>
<button class="btn filter"></button>
```